# ASP.NET HTML - Textboxes are extremely close together and need help putting space in between them

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Send your comments.</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FromName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FromName)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FromEmail, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromEmail, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FromEmail)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Message, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Message, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Message)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Send" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I have tried using clearfix, as well as modifying the css margins in form-group. If anyone has any suggestions, feel free. Program works perfectly, just the formatting that is off.

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using? Depending on that you may be missing come classes. Try updating your divs to `<div class="form-group row">`

Comment: Could you please provide more information? Looks like you're having CSS trouble applying **bootstrap** with **razor**. Try to compare what was rendered with the **BS** documentation. :)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using `clearfix` in the wrong place?

Just add it along side `form-group`

```
<div class="form-group clearfix">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try either one will solve the problem.

- Add the class `form-horizontal` to the form

or

- Add the class `row` to the `<div class="form-group">`